# How do I draw big square brackets around forest nodes?

Tags: nodes, forest, brackets

I'd like to write node features between big square brackets in a tree (I use forest), as in the example below. What function could I use?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! What you try so far?

Comment: You could just do `{$\left[\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}MODAL\\+Tns\\+AGR\end{tabular}\right]$}` as thte content of the node but you could also create a normal node and add the brackets later, similar to how the `matrix` library provides [delimiter keys](https://tikz.dev/library-matrix#sec-59.3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `\bracketMe` which places its argument in a `tabular` (text mode) and puts `[` and `]` around it.
2. As above but by using the general and more customizable `\delimitMe` to apply `\delimitMe` automatically.
3. Using the `bracket` style key that uses customized `left delimiter` and `right delimiter` functions of the [`matrix` library](https://tikz.dev/library-matrix#sec-59.3).

The third option is a lot of TikZ overhead (and with the same customizability) but might be a viable solution in case `\bracketmatrix` can't be used (I don't know when that would be, though).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

% 1.
\newcommand*\bracketMe[2][c]{$\left[\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}\right]$}

% 2.
\newcommand*\delimitMe[4]{$\left#2\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#4\end{tabular}\right#3$}
\forestset{
  delimit me/.style 2 args={content/.expanded={\noexpand\delimitMe{c}{#1}{#2}{\forestoption{content}}}},
  bracket me/.style={delimit me=[]}}

% 3.
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  left delimiter'/.style 2 args={append after command={%
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfcurrentinnerysep{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}}
    \tikz@delimiter{east}{west}{every delimiter,every left delimiter,#2}{south}{north}{#1}{.}%
    {\dimexpr\pgf@y-\pgfcurrentinnerysep*2}}},
  right delimiter'/.style 2 args={append after command={%
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfcurrentinnerysep{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}}
    \tikz@delimiter{west}{east}{every delimiter,every right delimiter,#2}{south}{north}{.}{#1}%
    {\dimexpr\pgf@y-\pgfcurrentinnerysep*2}}}}
\makeatother
\forestset{
  left delimiter/.style 2 args={
    tikz+={\path[late options={name=\forestoption{name},left delimiter'={#1}{#2}}];}},
  right delimiter/.style 2 args={
    tikz+={\path[late options={name=\forestoption{name},right delimiter'={#1}{#2}}];}},
  lr delimiters/.style 2 args={
    left delimiter/.expanded={#1}{xshift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}+.3333ex}},
    right delimiter/.expanded={#2}{xshift={-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}+.3333ex)}}},
  bracket/.style={lr delimiters=[]}}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest} % using \bracketmatrx
[root
  [I\textsuperscript 0
    [\bracketMe{MODAL\\+Tns\\+AGR}
      []
    ]
  ]
  [VP
    [(SPEC)]
    [$\bar{\textrm{V}}$
      [V\textsuperscript 0]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest} % using \bracketmatrix by way of bracket me
[root
  [I\textsuperscript 0
    [MODAL\\+Tns\\+AGR, bracket me
      []
    ]
  ]
  [VP
    [(SPEC)]
    [$\bar{\textrm{V}}$
      [V\textsuperscript 0]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}% using bracket on the multiline node
[root
  [I\textsuperscript 0
    [MODAL\\+Tns\\+AGR, align=center, bracket
      []
    ]
  ]
  [VP
    [(SPEC)]
    [$\bar{\textrm{V}}$
      [V\textsuperscript 0]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See, if this is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    math content,
    s sep = 3mm, 
    l sep = 9mm,  
           }
[?
    [I^0
        [\begin{bmatrix}
            \text{MODAL}\\ 
            \text{+ Tns}\\ 
            \text{+AGR}\end{bmatrix}]
    ]
    [VP 
        [\text{(SPEC)}] 
        [V 
            [V^0]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]