# Conjunction in truth trees

Tags: forest, logic, prooftrees

while we are creating truth trees we use something called "hook" to write conjunctions instead of simply writing them line by line. I don't know if it is called something else in English.

[image]

I mean the shapes that I marked with red arrows. So this one:

[image]

Should look like this:

[image]

Is this something achievable with **prooftrees** or should I use something like **forest**, **tikz-qtree**? It would be wonderful if you can show me how to draw it on the

```
[{Ha}, just={(5)}, no line no
[{Fa}, just={(5)}, no line no, my text={6}
```

part of the following code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage[paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm]{geometry}
\geometry
    {
        total={120mm,200mm},
    }
 \forestset{
    branchcomment/.style={
      my text/.style={
        label={[yshift=-5pt]below:{##1}},
        l sep'+=5pt,
      },
    },
  }
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
\begin{prooftree}
    {
        to prove={\forall x(Fx \rightarrow \lnot Gx),\, \exists x(Hx \wedge Fx) \therefore \exists x(Hx \wedge \lnot Gx)},
        auto move=false,
        single branches=false,
        for tree={s sep'=10mm},
        just sep=2.5em,
        close with={\ensuremath{\bigtimes}},
        branchcomment,
    }
    [{\forall x(Fx \rightarrow \lnot Gx)},just={(Ön)}, line no override={3}
        [{\exists x(Hx \wedge Fx)},just={(Ön)}, line no override={2}
            [{\lnot \exists x(Hx \wedge \lnot Gx)},just={($\lnot$Sn)}, line no override={1}
                [{\forall x \lnot (Hx \wedge \lnot Gx)},just={(1. N.D.K)}, line no override={4}
                    [{Ha \wedge Fa},just={(2. Özelleme)}, line no override={5}
                        [{Fa \rightarrow \lnot Ga}, just={(3. Özelleme)}, line no override={6}
                            [{\lnot (Ha \wedge \lnot Ga)},just={(4. Özelleme)}, line no override={7}
                            [{Ha}, just={(5)}, no line no
                                [{Fa}, just={(5)}, no line no, my text={6}
                                    [{\lnot Fa}, no line no, close]
                                    [{\lnot Ga}, no line no, my text={7}
                                        [{\lnot Ha}, no line no, close]
                                        [{Ga}, no line no, close]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

I still would be happy as a clam too if you can simply show on this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
    {
    }
    [{p \wedge q}
        [{p}, just={(1)}
            [{q}, just={(1)}]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Thank you all for your answers in advance.

Comment: Maybe this answer by @Qrrbrbirlbel can point you in the right direction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672905/29873

Comment: Thank you for pointing out but that is for wrapping the text. I need something that connects two line and shows they are coming from same line. So, I also need to make them share the same justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code shows how to define a new style `append wffs=<integer>` which takes an integer argument. It should be added to the options for the final of the wffs to be bracketed together and the value should equal the number of additional wffs to be bracketed with this one. For example, if you want the wffs on lines 3 and 4 to be bracketed, add `append wffs=1` to the wff on line 4.

Use the standard `just=<whatever>` syntax to specify the justification. For example, `append wffs=1, just={1,2,MP}` or whatever. So for your example, you'd write

```
                [{Ha}, no line no
                [{Fa}, no line no, my text={6}, just=(5), append wffs=1
```

This will bracket the two wffs and place `(5)` to the right of the line.

This should work even if a wff to be bracketed is longer than the current (final) wff because the code uses `forest`'s `fit to` option to get a box including all the affected wffs and uses that to draw the bracket.

```
\forestset{
  append wffs/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for nodewalk={fake=c,*{#1}u}{just=}%
    },
    before drawing tree={
      tikz+/.process={Ow1{name}{%
          \node (##1 append box) [inner sep=0pt, fit to={c*{#1}u}] {};
          \draw (##1 append box.north east) ++(-2.5pt,0pt) -| (##1 append box.south east) -- ++(-2.5pt,0pt);
        }%
      },
      tempdima/.max={>O{max x}}{c*{#1}u},
      for nodewalk/.process={%
        O Rw1+d OOw2+d w3 {proof tree proof line no}{tempdima}{##1+2.5pt}{y}{!*{#1}u.y}{(##1+##2)/2}
        {%
          {name=just ##1}{x'=##2,y'=##3}%
        }%
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Note that this overrides any justifications set for the appended wffs, so it's important to specify `just` for the same wff as `append wffs`.

[image: tableau using append wffs style]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage[paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm]{geometry}
\geometry
{
  total={120mm,200mm},
}
\forestset{
  branchcomment/.style={
    my text/.style={
      label={[yshift=-5pt]below:{##1}},
      l sep'+=5pt,
    },
  },
  append wffs/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for nodewalk={fake=c,*{#1}u}{just=}%
    },
    before drawing tree={
      tikz+/.process={Ow1{name}{%
          \node (##1 append box) [inner sep=0pt, fit to={c*{#1}u}] {};
          \draw (##1 append box.north east) ++(-2.5pt,0pt) -| (##1 append box.south east) -- ++(-2.5pt,0pt);
        }%
      },
      tempdima/.max={>O{max x}}{c*{#1}u},
      for nodewalk/.process={%
        O Rw1+d OOw2+d w3 {proof tree proof line no}{tempdima}{##1+2.5pt}{y}{!*{#1}u.y}{(##1+##2)/2}
        {%
          {name=just ##1}{x'=##2,y'=##3}%
        }%
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}%
\begin{prooftree}
  {
      to prove={\forall x(Fx \rightarrow \lnot Gx),\, \exists x(Hx \wedge Fx) \therefore \exists x(Hx \wedge \lnot Gx)},
      auto move=false,
      single branches=false,
      for tree={s sep'=10mm},
      just sep'=2.5em,
      close with={\ensuremath{\bigtimes}},
      branchcomment,
  }
  [{\forall x(Fx \rightarrow \lnot Gx)},just={(Ön)}, line no override={3}
    [{\exists x(Hx \wedge Fx)},just={(Ön)}, line no override={2}
      [{\lnot \exists x(Hx \wedge \lnot Gx)},just={($\lnot$Sn)}, line no override={1}
        [{\forall x \lnot (Hx \wedge \lnot Gx)},just={(1. N.D.K)}, line no override={4}
          [{Ha \wedge Fa},just={(2. Özelleme)}, line no override={5}
            [{Fa \rightarrow \lnot Ga}, just={(3. Özelleme)}, line no override={6}
              [{\lnot (Ha \wedge \lnot Ga)},just={(4. Özelleme)}, line no override={7}
                [{Ha}, no line no
                [{Fa}, no line no, my text={6}, just=(5), append wffs=1
                    [{\lnot Fa}, no line no, close]
                    [{\lnot Ga}, no line no, my text={7}
                      [{\lnot Ha}, no line no, close]
                      [{Ga}, no line no, close]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

As it stands, this will fail if you do something 'weird' such as centring your justifications or switching their anchors to `east` or if you put justifications on the other side of the tree. However, it 'should' work reasonably robustly for tableaux roughly like your example, even if you use several `append wffs` in the same tree, bracket several wffs or bracket wffs of different lengths.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what happened but it works like a charm. I use these hooks all the time. 9/10 tableaux I typeset contains this and it's nothing but a headache to me for a while. Especially trees like first image I shared is a total freak show. I couldn't progress this much without your helps, thank you so much. I'll bother you one more question: When I add the `tikz` code you wrote to another tree it is distant from the line, how can I solve it? And how can I define a global setting to do this job for me, since it is not easy to write it roughly 6 times per tree.

Comment: @arkh3us See new answer above. I wrote this before reading your comment, but I hope it should help. (I'm not quite sure why you'd get the justification distant from the line with my original code, but it wasn't very thorough.)

Comment: It could ideally be more efficient, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you want in your larger code example, but here's a general method that you can use exemplified with your smaller example.  I've used the `ext.paths.ortho` TikZ library, part of the `tikz-ext` suite of libraries.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\tikzset{ortho/rl distance=.5em} % set width of the horizontal part
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
    {
    }
    [{p \wedge q}
        [{p},name=p, just={(1)}
            [{q},name=q, just={(1)}]]]
\draw (p.east) r-rl (q.east);
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

If you want the lines to actually enclose the text, you could use the coordinates `(p.north east)` and `(q.south east)` which would extend them to the edge of the nodes themselves.

[image: output of code]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I just wonder if I can align the justifications to the line.

Comment: @arkh3us I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @arkh3us You can ;).